# Unix executable files not found in $PATH

Tags: ubuntu, go, ls, pwd

I have a problem when using Go. Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    output, err := exec.Command("pwd").Output()
    fmt.Println(string(output), err)

    output, err = exec.Command("ls", "-l").Output()
    fmt.Println(string(output), err)
}
```

When I run this, I get the following errors.

> err exec: "pwd": executable file not found in $PATH;
>
> err exec: "ls": executable file not found in $PATH

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Comment: Works for me. You should check that the user running the program really have access to the wanted command: the user may not be the one you want/believe…

Comment: Check your environmental variable $PATH. It could have been changed in ~/.bashrc file. Otherwise, your code is working without errors.

Comment: thanks! is my $PATH wrong, is work!

Comment: Why does no-one answer the obvious question here which is where is the 'go' executable?

Comment: what is your $PATH? if you're still having problems try to print it from golang

Comment: How u run your code? `go build` or `go run` or `sudo go`? And check your go's owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I thought that the issue was caused because the code did not reside in `~/go/src/<bitbucket.org>/<username>/`, but it turns out that it will also run successful if it is executed from the home directory, i.e. `~/`. Probably, like already was mentioned in the comments, the commands `pwd` and `ls` were not in the path or the program was executed as another user.